# A non-special Aronszajn tree with a stationary set that is non-stationary with respect to the tree

Tags: set-theory, trees, infinite-combinatorics

Is there any example of a ($\omega_1$-)Aronszajn tree $T$ that is non-special and there exists a stationary subset $S\subset \omega_1$ such that $S$ is not stationary with respect to $T$?

- A tree being non-special means it can't be written as a countable union of antichains
- $S\subset \omega_1$ is not stationary with respect to $T$ if there exists a regressive function $f: T\restriction S \to T$ (for any non-minimal $t\in T$, $f(t)<_T t$), for all $t\in T$, $f^{-1}\{t\}$ is a countable union of antichains.

A set is non-stationary in $\omega_1$ then it is non-stationary with respect to any tree. A tree is special iff $\omega_1$ is non-stationary with respect to the tree. If we let $NS_T$ denote the collection of non-stationary subsets of $\omega_1$ with respect to $T$, then I'm asking for an Aronszajn example such that $NS_{\omega_1}\subsetneq NS_T \subsetneq P(\omega_1)$.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it is consistent that all Aronszajn trees are special. So explicit examples are certainly impossible. And as far as consistency takes you, pick your favorite model with a Suslin tree, and a non-stationary subset of $\omega_1$.

Comment: I want a stationary subset of $\omega_1$.

Comment: I misread, sorry. :)

Comment: Have you tried building one assuming $\Diamond(S)$, for a costationary $S$?

Comment: @PaulLarson: I thought about that but I didn't see how that helps. I also tried finding a non-special Aronszajn subtree of $T(S)$, which is the tree of all closed (in $\omega_1$) countable sets ordered by end-extension. $NS_{T(S)}=\{A\subset \omega_1: A\cap S\in NS_{\omega_1}\}$.

Comment: You may look at [A survey of special Aronszajn trees ](http://logika.ff.cuni.cz/radek/papers/Honzik_Stejskalova_AronszajnTrees.pdf)

Comment: You can find such trees in Section 3 of Chapter IX of Shelah's 'Proper and Improper Forcing'. In Shelah's terminology, if you had a tree $T$ that was $S$-st-special but not special for $S$ a stationary subset of $\omega_1$ consisting of limit ordinals, you would be done. You can do this using Lemma 3.9 there (using $\diamondsuit^*(\omega_1\setminus S)$), or the stuff in Section 4 (start with a Suslin tree $T$ and force with $Q(T,S)$ for some $S\subseteq \omega_1$ stationary co-stationary and consisting of limit ordinals).

Comment: @tci: thanks for the reference. it answers the question. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @PaulLarson: slightly modifying Shelah's construction, just assuming $\Diamond(S^c)$, it is possible to get an $\omega$-distributive tree $T$ such that $S$ is non-stationary with respect to $T$. Forcing with $T$ preserves $\omega_1$ but necessarily shoots a club in $S^c$.